# java ews api - network credentials?

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am truing to use Java EWS (Exchange Web Services) API. The problem is my Exchange requires ntlm, while i only see WebCredentials available in that api, and not NetworkCredentials (something that's available in .net). And I of course get unauthorized exception using webcredentials.Any ideas on how to connect to MS Exchange with ntlm using Java EWS API?

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("me@me.me", "&*^*^");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials( "username", "pass");
    service.setCredentials( credentials );    
    service.setUrl( new URI("http://your/wsdlUrl.asmx?wsdl") );
```

From there you can call the Exchange Service methods for finding items or folders using search filters.

Comment: username is without the domain or email address

Comment: Surely the url should be `"https://your_exchange_server/EWS/Exchange.asmx"` and not contain the `?wsdl` at the end?

Comment: But how about NTLM authentication without password?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Managed API for EWS Java (it is out there for Java). It seems to be riddled with bugs, but includes a NTLM implementation. At any rate it basically uses JCIFS to do this.

Comment: hm... which one would it be? can you give me the link please?

Comment: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi ... but again look at all the comments.... choose the download tab to actually download

Comment: The EWS Java API was released recently as an open source project with MIT license on GitHub. Developers are welcome to contribute fixes to bugs they encounter.  https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/